# (Move) push_back on nested vector

Tags: vector, data-structures, diem, move-lang

I have a data type defined as

```
let digests: vector<vector<u8>>;
```

In this `digests` vector if I try to use `push_back` to insert another vector as the following

```
let digest1: vector<u8>;
let digests: vector<vector<u8>>;

digest1 = h"00";
digests = Vector.empty<vector<u8>>();

Vector.push_back<vector<u8>>(
                &mut digests, 
                copy(digest1)
            );
```

The tests fail on `push_back` with the following error.

```
[106] DiscardedTransaction(TransactionOutput { write_set: WriteSet(WriteSetMut { write_set: [] }), events: [], gas_used: 0, status: Discard(VMStatus { major_status: UNKNOWN_INVARIANT_VIOLATION_ERROR, sub_status: None, message: Some("vector elem type mismatch -- expected Vector(U8), got General([])") }) })
```

I am a bit lost with this error. Also, are there any better alternatives to implement a nested vector?

*I am using move intermediate representation to write the above*

Answer (score 0):

This was identified as a bug and fixed here: https://community.libra.org/t/push-back-on-a-vector-with-other-vectors/2706/3